# How to create a JavaScript Object using data in database?

Tags: javascript, php, json

I want to create a **JavaScript object** as follows.

```
var codropsEvents = {
    '02-02-2017' : '<span>Some txt from database</span><span>Some txt from database</span>',
    '02-05-2017' : '<span>Some txt from database</span><span>Some txt from database</span>'
};
```

For that, the js function I developed is as follows.

```
function setEventsCalendar() {
    var codropsEvents
    try {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "calendarData.php",
            dataType: "text",
            async: false,
            success: function(msg) {
                codropsEvents = "{" + msg + "}";
                codropsEvents = JSON.parse(codropsEvents);
            }
        });

        return codropsEvents;
    } catch(ex) {
        alert(ex);
    }
}

var codropsEvents = setEventsCalendar();
```

**calendarData.php** file generates following as a **String** (Including all colons, commas, tags etc.)

```
'02-02-2017' : '<span>Some txt from database</span><span>Some txt from database</span>', '02-08-2017' : '<span>Some txt from database</span><span>Some txt from database</span>'
```

How can I create the JS object using that String? Or any other proper way to get the expected result.

Comment: That's not valid JSON. In JSON, strings are surrounded with double quotes, not single quotes. Why aren't you using `json_encode()` in the PHP script?

Comment: One thing more  async: false has been deprecated, please do not use it.

Comment: @Barmar I tried 'json_encode()'. But still I couldn't get the expected result.  Therefore, could you be more specific so that I can adapt it in my code.

Comment: @Kumar Thank you very much for the advice

Comment: If PHP returns valid JSON, you don't need to concatenate `{` and `}` in the Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make an array like in php-

```
$dataArray = ['02-02-2017' => '<span>Some txt from database</span><span>Some txt from database</span>',
              '02-05-2017' => '<span>Some txt from database</span><span>Some txt from database</span>'];
// and this array to json string and print it,
 echo json_encode($dataArray,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

Now in ajax part you can simply get data in json format by changing dataType to `json`; msg parameter of success function is javascript object or having code like `codropsEvents = JSON.parse(msg);` inside success function.